# Converting .parquet file to CSV using Pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, bigdata

I have a .parquet file and I am using PyArrow.
I converted the .parquet file into a table using the following code:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
filepath = "xxx"  # This contains the exact location of the file on the server
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
table = pq.read_table(filepath)
```

Performing `table.shape` returned `(39014 rows, 19 columns)`.

The schema of the table is:

```
col1: int64 not null
col2: string not null
col3: string not null
col4: int64 not null
col5: string not null
col6: string not null
col7: int64 not null
col8: int64 not null
col9: string not null
col10: string not null
col11: string not null
col12: string not null
col13: string not null
col14: string not null
col15: string not null
col16: int64 not null
col17: int64 not null
col18: int64 not null
col19: string not null
```

When performing `p = table.to_pandas()` I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name RangeIndex

How do I convert this parquet file into a dataframe and then CSV ?
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of pyarrow and pandas are you using? They might not be compatible. In the last days Pandas released a new version and PyArrow will release also a new one. It might help for now to up/downgrade your Pandas installation until the new pyarrow release drops.

Comment: Try `from pandas import RangeIndex` and update your question with the output

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

def read_pyarrow(path, nthreads=1):
    return pq.read_table(path, nthreads=nthreads).to_pandas()

path = './test.parquet'
df1 = read_pyarrow(path)

df1.to_csv(
    './test.csv',
    sep='|',
    index=False,
    mode='w',
    line_terminator='\n',
    encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Technically if the separator is "|" then it's not a CSV but the principle is the same :-)